# Namespace reflection in PHP

Tags: php, oop, reflection

i'm trying to preform a check of what classes exists within a namespace and i've been hinted towards using reflection. but it appears that PHP is just lacking the classes/functions to preform namespace reflections.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first glance at the docs sugguests you are correct.  As a result you'd probably have to enumerate all ([get_declared_classes](https://www.php.net/get_declared_classes)), and then for every single class, call `ReflectionClass::inNamespace()`

Comment: Well `inNamespace` only tells whether the class is in a namespace, not in a specific one, you would have to compare with [`getNamespaceName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php) for that

Answer (score 1):

You can [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) function to know classes that have been defined in your namespace.

Comment: I don't see any mention of namespaces in that doc -- does `get_declared_classes` return all classes in all namespaces?